# CSS Opacity animation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, angularjs, fade

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying not to depend on jQuery for this fadeIn animation I want.

I've tried ng-animate and .fade-enter + .fade-enter.fade-enter-active, but I'm getting nowhere.

my footer CSS looks like this:

```
footer {
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And I'm trying to animate it such that opacity goes to 1 in 2 seconds.

This is the version of Angular I am running:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

How would I do this animation with Angular and CSS and without jQuery?

Comment: You can create AngularJS demos of code at http://plnkr.co/, which will help understand what you've tried.

Comment: Also, you might check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12489271/451969 Which uses pure CSS, with jQuery toggling a class. Note: Only works in Webkit. Technically, what you need to do is modify the `opacity` for an element from `1` to `0` and vice versa, so some Javascript to start at one value and increment/decrement over a period of time (`setTimeout()`) to the other value is what you need.

Comment: Hey Jared,  Thanks for the link.  I could also use jQuery's .animate(), but I want to use CSS and Angular exclusively.  Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u3ENd655gl1JwDM06Aso

Comment: Have you tried the official docs? http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/appear

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just not getting it :(  I also can't get it to trigger on a click.  In my head, it makes sense for ng-click="replaceThis()" ng-animate="{{replaceThisVariable}}", but it doesn't work at all for me.  I'm definitely doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Are you stuck with version 1.1.5 or can you use the newly released version 1.2 RC1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do a fade in/out animation in Angular 1.1.5:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-init="visible = true">
  <button ng-click="visible = !visible">Show/Hide</button>
  <p ng-show="visible" ng-animate="'fade'">Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.fade-hide, .fade-show {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.fade-hide {
  opacity:1;
}

.fade-hide.fade-hide-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.fade-show {
  opacity:0;
}

.fade-show.fade-show-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nm8JbkVx4su3Dlyw84Nh).

This [blog post](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html) has good information on animations in Angular 1.1.5. And I suggest taking a look at the [new animation system](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) released in Angular 1.2 RC1.

Answer (score 0):

All you need about animation can be found on their documentation

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="checked=true">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"> Is Visible...
  </label>
  <div class="check-element sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked" style="clear:both;">Visible...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sample-show-hide {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
 }

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
   opacity:0;
}
```

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations