# Spinner in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use a spinner which I can show during some of the rest api calls for a better UX. I have come across many existing github projects which does exactly similar things.

https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy
      https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner

But I'm not able to use any of the existing projects. I think before I start writing something of my own, I want to know if things which I'm looking for can be done using these projects or any other existing project.

**Requirement:**

1. During some of the rest api calls like uploading images, fetching some data, deleting images, etc, I want to show a spinner with background faded. Once I have the result, I can show the background again and remove the spinner.
2. I want to use this spinner with start/stop from my controller not from my html.
3. I don't want this spinner for all the xhr requests by default.

I think angular-busy [demo](http://cgross.github.io/angular-busy/demo/) does solves most of the above requirements except that it needs a promise param in html. Is there anyway by which I can control the start/stop dynamically from my controller rather than giving a promise.

Angular-spinner [demo](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) is good but it doesn't fade out background. Is there any way to fade out background ?

Can anyone give me some pointers how exactly can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I always create my own spinner with this logic:

js:

```
app.directive('ngSpinnerBar', ['$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // by defult hide the spinner bar
                element.addClass('hide'); 

                // count how many time requests were sent to the server
                // so when they all done the spinner will be removed
                scope.counter = 0;

                $rootScope.$on('$stateNetworkRequestStarted', function () {
                    scope.counter++;
                    element.removeClass('hide'); // show spinner bar
                    //  $('body').addClass('page-on-load');
                });

                $rootScope.$on('$stateNetworkRequestEnded', function () {
                    scope.counter--;
                    if (scope.counter <= 0) {
                        scope.counter = 0;
                        element.addClass('hide'); // show spinner bar
                        //  $('body').removeClass('page-on-load'); // remove page loading indicator
                    }

                });

            }
        };
    }
])
```

html:

```
<div ng-spinner-bar></div>
```

As you can see every time i send a request to the api i show the spinner (css create the spinning - [link](http://www.css-spinners.com/)) and when result come back i send event to hide the spinner.

if you want to make things easier for you, you should create a service which send all the api requests (wrap $http). that way you can ensure every request will show the spinner.

**EDIT**

the first result in google gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422859/4573534) - fade background in angular

Comment: And how can we make background fade out ?

Comment: Can't we use any of the existing modules which I have mentioned in my question for solving the pupose ?

Comment: You could but that way you can't controll the dom while the spinner is active. In my code you can use jquery or anther plugin to fade the background.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like http://bsalex.github.io/angular-loading-overlay/_site/ fits the requirements.

For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app-http-integration-with-reference-id-and-matchers', [
    'bsLoadingOverlay',
    'bsLoadingOverlayHttpInterceptor'
  ])
  .factory('randomTextInterceptor', function(bsLoadingOverlayHttpInterceptorFactoryFactory) {
    return bsLoadingOverlayHttpInterceptorFactoryFactory({
      referenceId: 'random-text-spinner',
      requestsMatcher: function(requestConfig) {
        return requestConfig.url.indexOf('hipsterjesus') !== -1;
      }
    });
  })
  .factory('randomUserInterceptor', function(bsLoadingOverlayHttpInterceptorFactoryFactory) {
    return bsLoadingOverlayHttpInterceptorFactoryFactory({
      referenceId: 'random-user-spinner',
      requestsMatcher: function(requestConfig) {
        return requestConfig.url.indexOf('randomuser') !== -1;
      }
    });
  })
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('randomTextInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('randomUserInterceptor');
  }).run(function($sce, bsLoadingOverlayService) {
    bsLoadingOverlayService.setGlobalConfig({
      /* 
          It is only an example, don't use this url in production.
          Copy this template to your code base or use integration with Spin.js (see Docs & Examples)
      */
      templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsalex/angular-loading-overlay/gh-pages/_site/loading-overlay-template.html')
    });
  });

app.controller('HttpIntegrationWithReferenceIdAndMatchersController', function($scope, $http, $sce, bsLoadingOverlayService) {
  $scope.randomText = $sce.trustAsHtml('Fetch result here');
  $scope.randomUser = undefined;

  $scope.fetchRandomText = function() {
    $http.get('http://hipsterjesus.com/api/')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.randomText = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.text);
      })
      .error(function() {
        $scope.randomText = $sce.trustAsHtml('Can not get the article');
      });
  };

  $scope.fetchRandomUser = function() {
    $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.randomUser = data.results[0];
      });
  };
});
```

```css
.random-result {
  display: flex;
  height: 170px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.random-result__text,
.random-result__user {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px dashed #C00;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.user__photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
.user__name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bsalex/angular-loading-overlay/master/dist/angular-loading-overlay.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bsalex/angular-loading-overlay-http-interceptor/master/dist/angular-loading-overlay-http-interceptor.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app-http-integration-with-reference-id-and-matchers">
  <div ng-controller="HttpIntegrationWithReferenceIdAndMatchersController">
    <div class="well well-lg bs-loading-container">
      <button ng-click="fetchRandomText()">Fetch random text</button>
      <button ng-click="fetchRandomUser()">Fetch random user</button>
      <div class="random-result">
        <div class="random-result__text" bs-loading-overlay bs-loading-overlay-reference-id="random-text-spinner" bs-loading-overlay-delay="3000">
          <p ng-bind-html="randomText"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="random-result__user user" bs-loading-overlay bs-loading-overlay-reference-id="random-user-spinner" bs-loading-overlay-delay="3000">
          <div ng-if="randomUser">
            <img ng-src="{{randomUser.picture.large}}" alt="" class="user__photo" />
            <p class="user__name">
              {{randomUser.name.first}} {{randomUser.name.last}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet above I've used integration with $http service. It matches requests and shows spinner with specified `referenceId`.

Also, the following features are available:

- You can show and hide spinners from controllers injecting bsLoadingOverlayService and calling `bsLoadingOverlayService.start();` and `bsLoadingOverlayService.stop();`;
- You can wrap Promises to show and hide spinners with `bsLoadingOverlayService.wrap()`;
- You can create preconfigured handlers (`bsLoadingOverlayService.createHandler({referenceId: 'handler-overlay'});`), to keep options in one place and then just call `preconfiguredHandler.start();` and `preconfiguredHandler.stop();`