# Bootstrap Background Darken With Dropdown Event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this.

I am trying to have the background of my website darken when the navigation menu drops down.

I can get it to work great when I hover over the menu after it's dropped, but not just by the menu dropping.

I have a div id "darkness" with an opacity of 70%.

Here is my javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').hover(function(){
    $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
}, function(){
    $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your '.dropdown-menu' class applied to? And have you tried $('.dropdown-menu').click or $('.dropdown-menu').toggle?

Comment: @Greg - Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0ezjLe1/) what you're looking for ?

Comment: @Greg -  It might be better to use the `show.bs.dropdown` and `hide.bs.dropdown` events. I have made an update to the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0ezjLe1/1/) .

Comment: I got i to work using this...    
  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0);

  });

Answer (score 1):

**Greg Fielding** Hi there.

A good way to do this would be to use **toggleClass** and place a wrapper around the content.

Here is the code I use for this sample.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapsed").click(function(){
    $("#coverthishere").toggleClass("coverall");
    });
});
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3sjz821/)** of this sample.

You will see I use the menu class **collapsed** as the trigger here.
And I target the `ID` **coverthishere** to add/remove the `class` **.coverall**.

This will still allow the menu to be on top and the cover to below the menu but on top of the body.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone... couldn't get these solutions to work correctly, but they did get me a little closer I think. I've been able to add the following JS to get my "darkness" div to fade in, but I can't figure out how to get it to fade out. Any thoughts? $(".collapsed").click(function(){
$('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
});

Comment: Hi Greg, Have a look at [**this example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488099/toggle-css3-fade) it works with the transition in and out like you are looking for I think. See **Jared Farrish** answer.